# Multiple cursors in STMCUBE-IDE

Tags: stm32cubeide

I want to replace only some occurrences of a variable, so I wonder if a multiple cursors option is available on the STMCUBE-IDE. If anyone knows, please reply. Thanks!

P.S: On Keil MDK, if you hold down the Ctrl key and use the left mouse click on the desired location, you can activate multiple cursors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it by random guessing.

it's Ctrl + Alt + LMB(left mouse button)